# iterate over a js array of objects, within each object, check a value in the object against all others for uniqueness, push to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is a good way to iterate over a js array of objects, and then within each object, check a value in the object against all others for uniqueness, and push to a new array.

I have an array of objects:

```
const weatherArray = [
  {
    dt: 1526871600
    dt_txt: "2018-05-21 03:22:00"
  },
  {
    dt: 1526871600
    dt_txt: "2018-05-22 03:30:00"
  },
  {
    dt: 1526871600
    dt_txt: "2018-05-21 03:50:00"
  },
  {
    dt: 1526871600
    dt_txt: "2018-05-23 03:17:00"
  },
  {
    dt: 1526871600
    dt_txt: "2018-05-23 03:23:00"
  }
]
```

I need to check each object and if the dt_txt (just date, not time eg: 2018-05-23, 2018-05-21 etc) is unique, push that object into a new array.

Below is what I have been trying, I commented to the code to show my train of thought.

```
var uniqueDays = []
function getDays(weatherArray) {
  // push first value to new array to compare against other items
  uniqueDays.push(weatherArray[0])
  // get just the yyyy-mm-dd from txt we're comparing against
  let firstDayString = weatherArray[0].dt_txt.split(" ")[0]

  weatherArray.map((day) => {
    let dayString = day.dt_txt.split(" ")[0]

    uniqueDays.map((uniqueDay, index) => {
      // get just the yyyy-mm-dd for new array items
      let unqiueDayString = uniqueDay.dt_txt.split(" ")[0]

      // if the value exists, do nothing
      if (unqiueDayString == dayString) {
        console.log('duplicate');
      } else {
        // otherwise push to new array (this is the issue)
        uniqueDays.push(day)
      }
    })
  })

  return uniqueDays
}
```

The issue I am having is that pushing to unique day's within it's own map function is causing a recursion issue. I know there has to be a better way to this. Any help or direction would be a big relief, I've been struggling with this for some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const weatherArray = [
  {
    dt: 1526871600,
    dt_txt: "2018-05-21 03:22:00"
  },
  {
    dt: 1526871600,
    dt_txt: "2018-05-22 03:30:00"
  },
  {
    dt: 1526871600,
    dt_txt: "2018-05-21 03:50:00"
  },
  {
    dt: 1526871600,
    dt_txt: "2018-05-23 03:17:00"
  },
  {
    dt: 1526871600,
    dt_txt: "2018-05-23 03:23:00"
  }
]

const seen = {};
const res = weatherArray.filter(function(dt){
  const date = dt.dt_txt.substring(0, 10);
  if (!seen[date]) {
    seen[date] = true;
    return true;
  }
});

console.log(res);
```

note that it's not clear how robust you need to parse your dates. Looking at your example all dates are in the format YYYY-MM-DD so I just used `substring` which would be faster than `split` or a regular expression.

As for why your code doesn't work it's because you're looping over `uniqueDays` but also pushing to it **inside the loop**. That's a no-no.

The code you posted is parsing the dates in `uniqueDays` every time. For a large collection that would be slow. The solution above only needs to parse the dates once per item so that would be faster.

Your code uses `map` but `map` generates a new array from whatever the function passed to map returns. In your case it's generating an array of undefined as in `[undefined, undefined, undefined]` and then throwing that array away. You probably wanted to use `forEach`.

I'm assuming you looped because you needed to keep parsing the dates. If you didn't parse the dates you can use `someArray.indexOf` to find if there is an entry in an array as in

```
const isInArray = someArray.indexOf(value) >= 0;
```

You can also use [`someArray.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) which takes a function so you could have used that to parse the dates.

But, finally, looking through an array is slow, checking if a property exists in an object is fast. Because of the differences between arrays and objects the algorithm for finding a property, a hashmap, is `O(1)` where as to find an value in an unsorted array is `O(N/2)`.

Let me add that @CertainPerformance's solution is also elegant. It's collecting the objects in `accum` and then has to iterate over that object to generate an array when it calls `Object.values`. For a large result array that would theoretically be slower than not having that second hidden loop.

Comment: such a beautiful function. thank you for your generous help

Comment: Just studied this again and wanted to say thanks again for taking the time. You really helped me grow here.

Answer (score 3):

You can group objects in an array with `.reduce`, putting each unique date into an object indexed by date and then getting that object's values:

```js
const weatherArray=[{dt:1526871600,dt_txt:"2018-05-21 03:22:00"},{dt:1526871600,dt_txt:"2018-05-22 03:30:00"},{dt:1526871600,dt_txt:"2018-05-21 03:50:00"},{dt:1526871600,dt_txt:"2018-05-23 03:17:00"},{dt:1526871600,dt_txt:"2018-05-23 03:23:00"}];

const output = 
  Object.values(
    weatherArray.reduce((accum, obj) => {
      const date = obj.dt_txt.slice(0, 10);
      if (!accum[date]) accum[date] = obj;
      return accum;
    }, {})
  );
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const newUniqWeatherArray = [];

weatherArray.forEach(x => {
  const date = x.dt_txt.split(' ')[0];

  if(!newUniqWeatherArray.some((x) => x.dt_txt.split(' ')[0] === date)){
    newUniqWeatherArray.push(x);
  }
})
```

Basically the pseudocode is as below:

- Loop thru weatherArray
- For each of the child, check if the date exist in new array

  - If not exist, push this object into the new array
  - else do nothing